# How to network Organizations?

Tags: organic-groups

I'm running OG 2.7.

I need to make it so ORG A can connect/ network with ORG B.

ORG A says "I'm affiliated with ORG B and want to show that connection." Currently, they would just select from an entity reference field containing a list of all ORGS, pick ORG B, and then ORG B would show up on ORG A's page as "in their network".

The problem is, ORG B may not agree that ORG A is affiliated and thus would want to approve or deny the affiliation. So I'm looking for a way to provide the same networking effect with approve/ deny functionality.

I've searched high and low for any glimpse of a way to achieve and have found nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just pointing me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no module which does this out-of-the-box for organic groups - the User Relationships module does this for users (https://www.drupal.org/project/user_relationships).

To achieve with groups, you could set up a similar system with flags and rules, i.e. someone can flag a group as a 'friend' or whatever, when they do, a rule sends a confirmation link to the friended group and they can then say they are friends with the other group (also using a flag). But I don't see why you'd do that as every person on the site is a user so you'd need to work out who has the ability to 'friend groups'.

A general observation - if you've looked around a lot for the functionality and it's not there, and it's fairly generic functionality (like 'friending') then you may be thinking in the wrong way about the problem and the problem may be solved by thinking about it different architecturally - I've been using Drupal for 8 years now and not had issues finding modules which fit to do the stuff I want to do.

HTH

Steve

Comment: Thank you for such an in-depth response. It does help. I have found a few out-of-box solutions for user networking, but nothing for content (After all, that's all an organization is - content). I will take a step back and try to rethink what we are trying to achieve. Thank you again.